# Will enabling row movements on list-partitioned table cause performance problems(oracle 11g r2)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, partition

Our incident management system has run for years, and the large quantity of closed incident tickets makes the table rather huge and slows down the search queries.

Our database version is oracle 11g r2 enterprise edition(partition option added). The concerned two large tables are: `incident` and `incident_area_info`(one incident corresponds to multiple incident_area_info, and they're joined using `incident_id`). So I want to use the following strategy:

1. Split incident table into two partitions: `closed_incidents`, `active_incidents`, using list-partition and `status` as partition key. Also, I manually enabled row movements on `incident` table and `incident_area_info` table, so that I can close the incident.
2. Split `incident_area_info` using reference partition.
3. Drop the original indexes and replace them with corresponding partitioned local indexes
4. Search open incidents only by default

I have applied this strategy in my developing environment and the search operation's execution time reduces to roughly 10% of the original on average(we have nearly 4 million closed incidents and only about 40,000 active incidents).

But "row movements" is disabled by default, so maybe enabling it will cause some performance problems.  Well, of course, when a row moves – it will be updated, deleted and re-inserted with all relevant index entries adjusted accordingly. And rowid will be modified after a row is moved(I'm quite sure we do not use rowid in our system, so this won't be a problem).

**Question1:**

Besides those mentioned above, will there be any other bad side effects when enabling row movements?

**Question2:**

I suspect that moving rows will create space holes in the original partition and the data file will be fragmented after long-term running. Is this true?

**Question3**

If question2 is true, then is there a way to remove these space holes, like `alter table mytable shrink space;`

**Question4**

[Here](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/row-movement/) one guy said '*everybody should be carefull when enabling row movement in production system since enabling row movement invalidates all dependent views, which could result into plenty invalidate objects*', but in my developing environment, after moving rows in incident table, the materialized view counting on incident table still works, and in `dba_mviews` everything seems to be fine. So, did I misunderstand what he means?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have any code that uses the `ROWID` and your status changes aren't causing too many rows to move between partitions (which seems unlikely if you're just creating two partitions), you should be fine.  The other downsides are generally of the "someone might do something that causes issues because they didn't understand the implications" such as shrinking a table.

Any space that is freed up when a row is deleted from the active partition should be reused on subsequent inserts into the table (assuming you have a standard OLTP application that is doing conventional-path inserts).  You shouldn't need to worry about "space holes".

I read the comment you quote as noting that the actual "ALTER TABLE <> ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT` command is DDL so it invalidates dependent objects and forces Oracle to recompile them.  It would be unfortunate if you ran that DDL at noon on a busy day in an OLTP system.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful~~ Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you think this question shall be closed? I have read the rules in [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) but still don't know why

Comment: @wander - I believe it is "on hold" because it probably makes more sense on the DBA site than here.  If so, it'll get moved over there and reopened.  It's not because you did anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Can I move this question to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)  manually or just wait. Really feel sad for being voted to close.